# Load data gradually on page load Angular 5, ODATA V3

Tags: angular, scroll, odata

I am using ODATA3 API to get data,
I am trying to load data on page scroll and the scroll is in-side a div.
please suggest a way to achieve this

Comment: You're far more likely to get help with this if you provide source code that actually demonstrates the problem, along with an exact description of what the expected result is, vs what the actual result is.  Please read here for details on how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @dgnuff i am new to stack overflow and still understanding better ways to communicate with people. thanks for the feed back

Comment: I haven't tried anything at yet, i am trying to load data on end of scroll to improve the performance. and the technologies i am using are ODATA and Angular5 as mentioned. any suggestion helps and i will get back when i find an answer Thanks